# Example of a connected set

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Can someone please give an example of a connected set? The formal definition is that if the set $X$ cannot be written as the union of two disjoint sets, $A$ and $B$, both open in $X$, then $X$ is connected. I cannot visualize what it means. For example, a convex set is connected. Why is it so? I looked up in the internet, it was of no help. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$, and more generally $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $n$, are connected (even path-connected).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more? It is not much of a help. $R$ is both open and closed too, so I cannot visualize it that way :)

Comment: There's many examples, so it's hard to see what would help you most. If you imagine a single "piece" of $\Bbb R^2$ which is intuitively "connected": you could always cut it through the middle into two disjoint sets. But they can't both be open, since one of them must contain the boundary, so the definition restricts disconnectedness to a decomposition into two disjoint, open sets.

Comment: For example, are the sets $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ connected? If so,  why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to think about the definition in the usual metric topology on the real line $\Bbb{R}^1$.  Here, for example, any finite open interval is connected, because if you try to separate it into two disjoint smaller open intervals, and say interval $A$ contains some point that is less than a point in interval $B$, then $x= \inf \tilde{A}$ is not in $A$ because arbitrary reals greater than   $\inf \tilde{A}$ are all in $\tilde{A}$ hence not in $A$. And $x$ is not in $B$ since if it were, for a sufficiently small by non-zero $\epsilon$, the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ would be in $B$; but the part of that neigborhood on the lesser side of $x$ is also in $A$ so the sets would not be disjoint.

Let's move on to $\Bbb{R}^2$, which is much more interesting.

For a convex set $K$, let's say we divide $K$ into two disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$. Now choose any arbitrary points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  By the definition of convexity, every point on the straight line $L$ between $a$ and $b$ is in $K$.  Now let's look at $C = L \cap A$ and $D = L \cap B$.  Since $L$ is topologically equivalent to a line segment in $\Bbb{R}^1$, it is connected, so for the disjoint open sets $C$ and $D$ there is a point $x$ that is neither in $C$ nor in $D$. $x$ demonstrates that  the disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ cannot cover $K$.  So the convex set $K$ is connected.  (This proof holds in any $\Bbb{R}^n$.)

But of course convexity is a much stronger condition than is needed for a set to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the reason $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$ is disconnected is that the definition really says that when considered as a subspace topology, the set cannot be written as the union of disjoint subsets.

Now in the subspace topology, the interval $[1,2]$ is in fact an open set, since any sufficiently small neighborhood *in that subspace* of any point $p$ in that interval lies entirely in that interval.  In particular, if we take $p = 2$, then any neighborhood with $\epsilon < 1$ lies entirely in $[1,2]$ because the points between 2 and 3 *are not in the subspace at all*.  So the decomposition into two disjoint open sets $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$ shows that this set is in fact not connected.